# Need help stacking or chaining functions together

Tags: lua

Im wondering how i can get something like this to work:

```
Test ={}

function Test:returnNumber5 ()
return 5 
end

function Test:add5( num ) 
return num + 5 
end


function randumFunction()
local num = Test:returnNumber5():add5() 
if num == 10 then

print(num)

end 
end
```

Im looking to stack or chain together code:

Test:returnNumber5():add5():add5():add5()

I dont understand how to setup long chains of functions. I understand how to call them and get them to do what i want when modding other games but dont know why its not working for my game. I put the test code above into my game and it just crashes my game with no details
Using Love2D framework

Please help if u can
Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about. Please edit your question to include some actual code you have tried, not pseudocode. Also show us your actual output and the output you're trying to get.

Comment: I re edited. Sorry its hard to word what im looking for

Comment: When I say "actual code", I mean code that we can copy, paste, and run ourselves. Lua keywords are not capitalized. "More code" should be commented. And format the code using the {} icon. We still don't know what you're trying to do by chaining functions. Add some `print` calls and tell us what output you should get.

Comment: Oh i see. Im new here. Dont know what youre all looking for. Will re edit thanks

Comment: Thats the best i can do with my phone for right now and the text editor on here is strange to work with lol ill get the hang of it soon hopefully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need constructor to object creation:

```lua
Test = {}

function Test:new()
  local o = {}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end
```

Second thing is to return self if you want use form `object:doSomething():doSomethingElse()`.

```lua
Test = {}

function Test:new()
  local o = {}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end

function Test:setNumber5()
  self.num = 5
  return self
end

function Test:add5() 
  self.num = self.num + 5
  return self
end

function Test:value() 
  return self.num
end


function randumFunction()
  local num = Test:new():setNumber5():add5():value()
  
  if num == 10 then
    print(num)
  end 
end
```

Comment: I knew it had something to do with metamethods! Lol thanks for the response

Comment: You are welcome. Member that you can click + if you think the answer is useful and click answer if it solve yours problem.

Comment: Hmm in not seeing any "+" sign. Also i dont think i can upvote an answer yet. I dont have enough points on my account